# Selecting subelements of objects in blender using python

Tags: python, scripting, blender

I'm using blender and I need to apply a material to comp_1_1_2_a. I have already tried to do this but it doesn't have attribute "materials" so I need to the material to each subelement of comp_1_1_2_a. How can I select them using python script?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object keeps a list of it's children as [`obj.children`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.children)

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects['comp_1_1_2_a'].children:
    if len(obj.material_slots) == 0:
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()
    obj.material_slots[0].material = bpy.data.materials['Material']
```